# getting webpage contents using curl_init not working for some links

Tags: php, curl

I am using this code to get contents of a url entered:-

```
class MetaTagParser
{
    public $metadata;
    private $html;
    private $url;




    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->url=$url;

        $this->html=  $this->file_get_contents_curl();

        $this->set_title();
        $this->set_meta_properties();
    }

    public function file_get_contents_curl()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }

    public function set_title()
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($this->html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

        $this->metadata['title'] = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
```

this class works for some pages but for some url like this one -
http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report_in-a-first-upa-govt-tweets-the-press_1745346
when I try to fetch data I get this error:-"Warning: get_meta_tags(http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report_in-a-first-upa-govt-tweets-the-press_1745346): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac\index.php on line 52"

it is not working, any ideas why this is happening??

Comment: the site doesn't like you scraping it.

Comment: but when this link is posted in facebook it easily fetches content out of the page....

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes website administrator is not stupid and know how to protect page from slurping and fetching so you have to trick his protection and present user agent like is coming from normal browser. Add this line:

```
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1",
```